# how to test if linear exists with a buffer with ArcPy

Tags: python, arcpy, buffer

I have a layer with several linear that I want to integrate into a database. But before integrating it, I have to test if the linear already exists or not. There is a lot of linear in the database so to make the processing faster I want to delimit the area I want to integrate first and test only on that area.
The rule I want to implement is to create a buffer around the incoming layer and to check if the linear in the database is 90% in the buffer zone. If it is the case then we consider that the incoming linear is a duplicate. If not, we integrate it.
[image]

I am looking for an algorithm that will allow me to save processing time and be as accurate as possible:

```
incom_undergroundspan = "AX_UNDERGROUNDSPAN"
db_undergroundspan = "ND_UNDERGROUNDSPAN

buffer = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(incom_undergroundspan, "test_buffer2", 5, "FULL", "ROUND")
#select only the linear contained at 90% in the buffer zone and delete the rest
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Clip](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm) tool to get the geometry of the lines within the buffer, then compare the length of the clipped lines with the original lines to get your percentage within the buffer